# Can't open anaconda-navigator on chromebook

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, chromebook

On my chromebook,I have installed Anaconda however when I enter anaconda-navigator into crosh I get this error message: "ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". I'm not sure why this happens, please can someone help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Anaconda needs a critical GL library file, in which case the whole directory seems to be missing according to the error message.

I believe it needs this library to render the page. I've seen the article this comes from and it asks you to allow the application to be installed in a directory called "/usr/local/conda3". I'm wondering if recent updates in Chrome OS may have separated the shared GL directory from the installation in this case or if there have been fundamental changes in the package in which it's requesting the import.

Since these changes can come along at any time and without warning, it might be best to create a crouton instance and install Ubuntu or some other crouton-compatible Linux distro on your Chromebook. Really this takes up quite a bit of space so I'd recommend having at least a 32GB SSD or EMMc drive on your system.